# ERROR TypeError: _co.getAdmin is not a function

Tags: html, angular, typescript, service, typeerror

This is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) application and it's something wrong with function `getAdmin()` in `auth.service`, but I have no idea what. When I moved this function to `app.component.ts` and changed to `"getAdmin()"` in HTML, it was OK, but I need this function in service. Please tell me what's wrong and how can I fix it.

PS. variable `admin` returns `'true'` or `'false'` as a string. 
It's e-Commerce app with user authentication, token and now I try to add admin.

auth.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient, private _router: Router) { }

getAdmin() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('admin') === 'true') return true;
    return false;
  }
}
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private _authService: AuthService) {
  }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<a class="nav-link" *ngIf="_authService.getAdmin()" routerLink="/admin" routerLinkActive="active">Admin</a>
```

Comment: In this line: `if (localStorage.getItem('admin') === 'true') return true;` are you checking for boolean `true` (no quotes)? Or string `'true'` (quotes). You have quotes so you are comparing a string to `localStorage.getItem('admin')`. You can see if `localStorage.getItem('admin')` is boolean or string or whatever with: `console.log(typeof localStorage.getItem('admin'));`

Comment: I checked it - when 'admin' is empty it returns object (null), if not -  returns string 'true' or 'false'. It works as it should, but thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always better to not call a function written in service from html . I think, you can resolve your current issue by changing your service scope from private to public. But the best way is to call a function inside component from html and call the  **getAdmin()** inside service from that function. The best practise is to keep the service scope to private itself while doing dependency injection.

app.component.html

```
<a class="nav-link" *ngIf="adminExists()" routerLink="/admin" routerLinkActive="active">Admin</a>
```

app.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient, private _router: Router) { }

getAdmin() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('admin') === 'true') return true;
    return false;
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private _authService: AuthService) {
  }
  adminExists(){
         return _authService.getAdmin();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change scope of service private to public in app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public _authService: AuthService) {
  }
}
```